how to change the language metadata displayed in the Details tab in the wpf.exe properties window
What does Language properties under the Details tab of the wpf.exe Properties window stand for?
I want to change "Language Netural", is it possible?

I tried the following steps, but the value did not change.
Is there any setting or code in the wpf project to achieve this?
Project Properties: Right-click on WPF project in Visual Studio and select "Properties."
Application Tab: In the project properties window, navigate to the "Application" tab.
Neutral Language: Under the "Neutral Language" dropdown, select the desired language for application.
Rebuild: After changing the neutral language setting, rebuild project to apply the changes.
I want to change "Language Neutral" to another option (e.g. French-fr), is this possible? Did I understand it wrong?
Edit:
[Assembly: System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US", System.Resources.UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)")]
[Assembly: System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", System.Resources.UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
in assembly.info
and
In the "Details" tab of the project.exe "Properties" window, change the language value from "Language Neutral" to "English"
Are they the same thing?
Why the language value can not change from "Language Neutral" to "English" when i set assembly.info ? (I also tried "fr-CA")

WPF Globalization and Localization Overview

Thanks. @Clemens. Could you describe the specific setup steps to modify the language value in the screenshot?

Why would you want to do that? You should read the linked article to develop a basic understanding of localization.

@Clemens.  Okay ,i will read it . My requirement is to set the Language option to one which is selected from Visual Studio.
There is a way to do it just by opening the EXE in Visual Studio and changing Version - Language however this is a manual way and not programmatic way. As and when exe is rebuild, the setting again gets removed. Is it possible?

@Clemens. Could you check my update in question ? Thanks for any reply.
